# ParallelArray or using ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, java-stream, fork-join

I must improve the performance of the following code but I don't know what (or how) to improve.

Currently, the code needs approx. 12 seconds for creating 94.478.400 objects.

I guess, I can speed this up by using something like `ForkJoinPool` or `ParallelArray`, but I don't know how or where to put this parallelization into my code.

Run the main-method:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.DoubleStream;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ParallelArray {

    // class to hold the permutations
    public static class Perm {

        public Perm(double a, double b, double c) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
            this.c = c;
        }

        double a;
        double b;
        double c;

        public String toString() {
            return "a=" + a + " b" + b + " c" + c;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        var perms = new ArrayList<Perm>();

        // create first permutations
        var perm1 = computePerm(2).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // create second permutations
        var perm2 = computePerm(-2).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // now I permutate again with perm1 and perm2:
        // iterating is fast
        for (var p1 : perm1) {
            for (var p2 : perm2) {
                // but this operation needs too long
                // can I speed this up by using fork-join or parallelArray?
                perms.add(new Perm(p1.a + p2.a, p1.b + p2.b, p1.c + p2.c));
            }
        }

        var end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // all the operations needs approx. 12 seconds
        System.out.println("diff: " + (end - start) + " millis");
        // it returns 94.478.400 objects
        System.out.println("objects: " + perms.size());
    }

    public static Stream<Perm> computePerm(int inc) {
        // I use a stream builder (to increase perfomance?)
        Stream.Builder<Perm> all = Stream.builder();
        // iterating is fast
        for (var a : arrayA().toArray()) {
            for (var b : arrayB().toArray()) {
                for (var c : arrayC().toArray()) {
                    // but this operation needs too long
                    // can I speed this up by using fork-join or parallelArray?
                    all.add(new Perm(a + inc, b + inc, c + inc));
                }
            }
        }

        return all.build();
    }

    public static IntStream arrayA() {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 30);
    }

    public static DoubleStream arrayB() {
        return DoubleStream.iterate(0, d -> d + 0.1).limit(18);
    }

    public static DoubleStream arrayC() {
        return DoubleStream.iterate(1, d -> d - 0.1).limit(18);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

After playing around I used an alternative method for computePerm(int c) which uses parallelStream:

```
    public static Stream<Perm> computePermParallel(int inc) {
        Stream<Perm> all = arrayA().parallel().boxed().flatMap(a ->
        {
            return arrayB().parallel().boxed().flatMap(b ->
            {
                return arrayC().parallel().mapToObj(c ->
                {
                    return new Perm(a + inc, b + inc, c + inc);
                });
            });
        });
        return all;
    }
```

However, when using `computePermParallel(int inc)` instead of `computePerm(int inc)`, the performance is even worser: instead of approx. 12 seconds, I need to wait approx. 19 seconds. So the non parallel version is much faster than the parallel version, even with such a huge amount of objects. Don't know why.

Comment: First you should work on the naming of your methods and variables. its a hell of a reading things like arrayA, arrayB without any real meaning.

Comment: Sorry, was to fast with sending.. check which is the real expensive operation - object creation, adding to Arraylist etc. before optimization, know your resources - memory, number of cores (beacuse of useful thread pool size), java version..

Comment: sorry, but you did exactly not what you dismiss as trivial suggestions. Just compare your comment above the code and the comment in the code. And in the code you comment about "operation needs too long" on a line where you do 2 things - creating a new object and adding it to the array list. And neither did you have told us about your thread pool size nor your memory size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions for your code

- Constant enlarging of your ArrayList causes a lot of copies and waisted time. As you already know the size upfront, pass it during initialization to your ArrayList. You can test this out with `var perms = new ArrayList<Perm>(94478400);`. The same can be achieved by setting invoking the following method on your arraylist         `perms.ensureCapacity(94478400);`
- In your case, there is no real advantage to using Streams since you create a stream with all elements. Then you change that stream to an List. A Stream will have benifits when you apply some kind of filtering before collecting. In your case you are just reallocating from a Stream to a List. You could directly add it into a list (with a correct initial value parameter)
- `ForkJoinPool`: Running things in parallell will not really help in your scenario. It would help if you had to run some expensive calculation. In your case you just create a new `Perm` object and put it in the perms list. The biggest problem is that `ArrayList` is not thread safe. Using it like you do now will cause you to lose data. Solution would be to let the `ForkJob` return a temp list that you merge in the full list after completion. Or by using a threadsafe list like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`. Both of these solutions create more Lists with data, and causes data to be copied. So instead of improving the runtime, it would most likely make it even worse.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things going on that are working against you ..

1. 94Million simple objects is something like 2-4GB of RAM used for that data - have you get enough RAM / configured for that ..
2. Continual re-allocation / copying of the ArrayList backing - you can help that with the [ensureCapacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity-int-) method of ArrayList (without this whenever the Array runs out of capacity, the backing storage has to grow and the data copied - for some cost but no gain).
3. Memory allocation is slow in Java .. if you can represent the data as say 3 arrays of double [not Double] already pre-sized - you vastly reduce the number of memory allocations (3 objects to allocate vs 94+ million) - you just have some code to execute then to initialise the data .. time should be much faster (although you might run into poor performance than you'd expect too - if it causes the CPU caches to be trashed).  Actually try pre-creating 1 94million row array and see how long that takes...
4. Unnecessary temporaries - each call of arrayB(), and arrayC() within the for loop over arrayA() results in a new temporary result getting built and then thrown away.  But in this example you can do this - and then there's only 3 calls (and sets of temporaries) made, not "nof B" * "nof C" * "nof A" + "nof B" * "nof A" + ...  [if the results need to vary on each loop - then ignore this, but as written it reads well but runs badly].

So change this -

```
for (var a : arrayA().toArray()) {
for (var b : arrayB().toArray()) {
for (var c : arrayC().toArray()) {
```

To this -

```
final int[] aArray = arrayA().toArray();
final double[] bArray = arrayB().toArray();
final double[] cArray = arrayC().toArray();
for (var a : aArray) {
for (var b : bArray) {
for (var c : cArray) {
```

Maybe you'll get it down an order of magnitude - but I suspect still at least 1 to 2 seconds - you're using a lot of memory - do you really need to (that sounds like a flaw for this particular case)??

To give you an idea of the relative cost of memory vs CPU you can test creating all the objects, then loop and set all the values and time the difference.

Comment: Re: RAM - a server VM has larger allocation pools by default (which will help)..